# How can I use ontrigger2d with and operation on unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

hi guys i want to check my game, if player came the door and take crystal level passed. I used this code but it doesnt work. How can i use and operations ontrigger2d.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && crystalCount >= 1)
            {
                // Destroy(other.gameObject);
                StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

instead:

```
StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
```